# Best way to ensure logged in users only see their data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security

This is going to sound like a stupid question, but I just wonder if I'm missing a trick anywhere.

Scenario is, I have a web application using Simple Memebership, where users can register to use it (invoice program for example).

However, they should only be able to view/update/remove information that they themselves add to the database/web app.

What is the best way to ensure the user only gets acces to their information?

Is it to add a Username field to every table, eg:

```
public class Invoice
{
     public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
     public int CustId { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
   public int ItemId { get; set; }
   public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

...and then in any controller that accesses the data, simply add a check for the username within every query, eg:

```
var Inv = db.Invoices.Where(x => x.UserName = User.Identity.Name);
var Itm = db.Items.Where(y => y.UserName = User.Identity.Name);
```

That is what I'm using currently, but wondered if this is **best practice**? Or if there is a simpler way now we're onto MVC4?

Is it best to use **UserName** or **UserId** from the **UserProfile** table, or does it matter?

**Update to add clarity following comments**

So 10 users have registered - and all created their own invoices.  I don't want any user seeing any other users invoice.

Thanks for any advice.

Mark

Comment: I don't this needs to be done on code level, but rather on database level. If a user posts something, best way is to link that post to the user. If a user browses to the website, the query should retrieve everything related to that user, so you don't have to deal with that in code.

Comment: How could you do it anywhere other than code?  The database wouldn't know who the user is would they (sorry if I've missed your point). thank you

Comment: At some point in the application, you need to retrieve the information the user can see. At that point, you already know who the user is, because they log in, so you should have a userid at least. Now when you retrieve the info, use that userid to perform your query and get the info linked to the right user.

Comment: What you have already works. The best way to protect a table row from unauthorized users, based on your specific scenario, is to tag each record per user. Between using a string (username) or an int (UserId), I would choose an int as it's better use in querying - more performant in joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up db relationships properly, you should be able to reference e.g. a user's invoices like so:

```
var invoices = dbContext.Users.first(u=>u.id == idParam).Invoices;
```

You can verify whether an invoice belongs to a user by testing

```
if(dbContext.Invoices.Any(i=>i.invoiceID))//invoice exists?
{
    //Invoice belongs to user?
    bool invoiceBelongsToUser = dbContext.Users.first(u=>u.id == idParam)
    .Invoices.Any(i=>i.invoiceID == invoiceIDParam);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Things i would do are:

1. Avoid passing in any form of user id/credential in post/query string, hold it somewhere secure, like encrypted in a cookie, and always user this when building your queries
2. If you have Ids passed back to your program as part of an edit, make sure the values have not been tampered with, if you output the id in a hidden field, make sure it is the same when it comes back as it went out (direct reference attack this is called)
3. if your application requests an edit, such as client/edit/4, always ensure that id 4 belongs to that user before displaying it.

Some good reading here on the top 10 vulnerabilities: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main

Comment: "encrypted in a cookie" is still not a secure place.

Comment: Hi - I'm using ASP.Net/MVC4 - and antiforgery token and authorize attributes etc - so I would have hoped that it stored whatever is needed to maintain the "logged in user" details, within it's framework, and not exposed it to the client.  Would I be wrong?

Comment: All the anti forgery token does is prevent xss attacks, you still need to protect against dra's

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) filter to the global.asax file to protect every action method of every controller.

And the controller no need to be authorized:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult LogOn()
```

[securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx)

Comment: Hi - sorry if I want' clear - what if there are two users, or two hundred users all creating their own invoices - my question is how is it best to stop them every seeing anyone else's invoices.  Thank you.